# What kind of medal is this?

Tags: military, identification

I found this medal in UK. As far as I know the medal is from CCCP. I am living in Latvia and it used to be CCCP as well. On the medal you can see LIEPAJ and if there is missing letter then that must be A because my city is named Liepāja.

Could anyone help me out with this? Thank you.

[image][image][image]

Comment: If you provided pictures with smooth lighting on an uncluttered background, like a sheet of paper, that would help with the identification.

Comment: This does not look like a Soviet medal. On a Soviet medal I expect the inscription to be in Russian (Letter i in Liepa... is not in Russian alphabet). I also see a big C which is not followed by P (R). It can be a medal of pre-1940 (independent) Latvia.